# Autofac register singleton twice

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

Is there a way in Autofac to register singleton as two different interfaces?

For example:

```
interface ILayer {} 
interface ILogicLayer{}
class LogicLayer : ILayer, ILogicLayer{ 
}
```

I want to register `LogicLayer` as single instance both as `ILayer` and `ILogicLayer`? How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<LogicLayer>()
    .As<ILayer>()
    .As<ILogicLayer>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just go ahead and:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var layer = new LogicLayer();
builder.RegisterInstance(layer).As<ILayer>();
builder.RegisterInstance(layer).As<ILogicLayer>();
```

Comment: The downside of this approcah is that LogicLayer has to be created when you register AutoFac which should be avoided especially if LogicLayer has its own dependencies that need injecting.

Comment: Absolutely, in those cases Maartens approach is better